# Should one track files in one's .history folder in git

Tags: git

Some files from my .history folder appear untracked in my status whenever I make changes. How would I control this, i.e. make is so these are automatically added or not added, rather than seeing this message?

I don't remember having to add these kind of files. Perhaps I need to fix something.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 ->   .history/Page1/index_20200315055719.html
 ->   .history/Page1/index_20200315055757.html
```

Any new changes I save generate these files. I know the files themselves are normal, but I don't think I am supposed to be adding them or having to deal with them.

Comment: This question is opinion based. It really depends on whether you want to track it in GIT or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[angular/angular-cli issue 12895](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12895) or [ejpcmac/xgen issue 19](https://github.com/ejpcmac/xgen/issues/19) both adds the `.history/` folder created by [VSCode extension `local-history`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history).

Since this is a local information generated by the user, it is best to be kept private, and not included in the source control commits.
You could for instance put sensitive information, before deleting it: that might still be recorded in those `.history/xxx` files.