# Is it safe to remove the history folder when committing to git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I created a webapi project in vs code. I am very new to source control. Is it safe to exclude the "History" folder when committing to git? This is my project structure:

[image]

When I try to setup the staging, it is shown that I have so many to stage because of the "history". Please check the image below:

[image]

If it is safe to remove the `history` folder when committing changes to git, how do I include it in my `.gitignore` file

Comment: I have no idea what `.history` is, but it's got nothing to do with GIT.

Comment: Looks like this is something to do with an [angular or code extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687569/should-one-track-files-in-ones-history-folder-in-git)

Comment: look like some version history files, make backup every time you save the file or save/backup every x minutes automatically

Answer (score -2):

You can ignore your history files just by simply writing file's name in `.gitignore` file.
It will directly get ignore every time it get generated.
First go to your working folder , then open `.gitignore` text file (if not shown, go to Home and change the setting to show hidden files) , the simple paste the name of file you want to hide or ignore.

Comment: They're not asking how .gitignore works, they're asking whether it is advisable to ignore this particular directory.